# How to use alpine js in wordpress ajax request?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, alpine.js

For a wordpress plugin using alpine js, I got an error to access of alpine data :

```
        var data = {
            'action'   : 'myWPAjaxAction',
            'data' :  JSON.stringify(this.ui.data)
        };

        jQuery.post( wp_ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                this.ui.submit.state = true; //cannot be found ! 
                this.ui.step = 5;
                var iFrame = document.getElementsById("yousign-iframe");
                iFrame.appendChild(response.view);
            } else {
                console.debug(response);
                this.ui.submit.state = false;
                this.ui.submit.errors = 'no_submit';
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            this.ui.submit.state = false;
            this.ui.submit.errors = 'no_submit';
        });
```

With this code inside an alpine function, I got an error :

> this.ui is undefined

How can I read/modify alpine data after ajax post request in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax, so `this` will refer to Alpine.js data object instead of jQuery:

```
jQuery.post( wp_ajax_object.ajax_url, data, (response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        this.ui.submit.state = true;
        this.ui.step = 5;
        var iFrame = document.getElementsById("yousign-iframe");
        iFrame.appendChild(response.view);
    } else {
        console.debug(response);
        this.ui.submit.state = false;
        this.ui.submit.errors = 'no_submit';
    }
}).fail(() => {
    this.ui.submit.state = false;
    this.ui.submit.errors = 'no_submit';
});
```

Comment: Or if you're not a fan of arrow syntax, you can always define a variable that references `this`. I usually do `let context = this`. Then you can call `context.ui` instead.